# How to place content within vertical menu?

Tags: html, css

I have the following vertical menus on my page. I want to insert content in each of these menus. I am unable to comprehend how to do it? When I click on the Menu 1 it should display content on the right of the page.

Find the screenshot.

[image]

```css
#button {
  width: 12em;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0 0 1em 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #90bade;
  color: #333;
}
#button ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
#button li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #90bade;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
}
#button li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 0.5em;
  border-left: 10px solid #1958b7;
  border-right: 10px solid #508fc4;
  background-color: #2175bc;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}
html>body #button li a {
  width: auto;
}
#button li a:hover {
  border-left: 10px solid #1c64d1;
  border-right: 10px solid #5ba3e0;
  background-color: #2586d7;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">'Menu 1'</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">'Menu 2'</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">'Menu 3'</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">'Menu 4'</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">'Menu 5'</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">'Menu 6'</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post screenshot

Comment: Are you using a CMS or making a static html site?

Comment: @AatifBandey..find the screenshot...

Comment: @adamk22...i think it is a static html site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello See my below demo when you click on the menu it will show the content right side i have only done this for 3 menu only others will be same

use jQuery to do this easily

```
 <script>

 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('#button ul li:first').addClass('active');
 $('.tab-content:not(:first)').hide();
 $('#button ul li a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var content = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(content).show();
    $(content).siblings('.tab-content').hide();
    });
 });
 </script>
```

I added a liitle Css

```
 .active {
  font-weight:bold;
  }
 .section {
 width:350px;
 float:left;
 padding:10px;
 }
 #button {
 float:left;
 }
```

also and some html elements for content section

```
 <div id="section-Menu1" class="tab-content">
 <h2>Menue 1</h2>
 <p>Welcome Menue 1 Text.</p>
 </div>
```

see the below **Fiddle** details

**If you dont want menu1 being active then just remove `$('#button ul li:first').addClass('active');`
and write `$('.tab-content').hide();`below instead of`$('.tab-content:not(:first)').hide();`

Hope It helps You
[MenuSidebarFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/pbzt812g/62/)

Comment: @Asif...Thanks for your help...let me just try it out

Comment: @Asif...can you check the updated fiddle..The contents are sticking to the menu...can we align them properly so that they dont stick with the menu...sorry i dont know much css hence struggling...http://jsfiddle.net/pbzt812g/61/

Comment: see the updated fiddle.And There is another way just add " .tab-content{float:right} in css file .See which one fits you .

Answer (score 0):

I have shown this content `on:hover` of menu item but you can create with `click` with javascript.

```css
#button {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0 0 1em 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #90bade;
  color: #333;
}

#button ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
}

#button li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #90bade;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
}

#button li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 0.5em;
  border-left: 10px solid #1958b7;
  border-right: 10px solid #508fc4;
  background-color: #2175bc;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 10em;
}

#button li a:hover {
  border-left: 10px solid #1c64d1;
  border-right: 10px solid #5ba3e0;
  background-color: #2586d7;
  color: #fff;
}

#button li div {
  background: #90bade;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  left: 197px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#button li:first-child div {
  display: block;
}

#button li a:hover ~ div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">'Menu 1'</a>
      <div>
        content 1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">'Menu 2'</a>
      <div>
        content 2
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">'Menu 3'</a>
      <div>
        content 3
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">'Menu 4'</a>
      <div>
        content 4
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">'Menu 5'</a>
      <div>
        content 5
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">'Menu 6'</a>
      <div>
        content 6
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Era..Thanks for your help...let me just try it out

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to be different here is a way to do it with no javascript (or jquery). It uses radio buttons.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
nav.menu {
  width: 10em;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #2175bc;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
nav.menu label .menu-item {
  width: calc(100%-20px);
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px .5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #90bade;
  border-left: 10px solid #1958b7;
  border-right: 10px solid #508fc4;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav.menu label input[name=menu-input] {
  display: none;
}
nav.menu label .menu-pane {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .15);
  left: calc(10em + 1px);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
nav.menu label .menu-item:hover,
nav.menu label input[name=menu-input]:checked ~ .menu-item {
  border-left-color: #1c64d1;
  border-right-color: #5ba3e0;
  background-color: #2586d7;
}
nav.menu label input[name=menu-input]:checked ~ .menu-pane {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
nav.menu label input[name=menu-input]:checked ~ .menu-item {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <label>
    <input name="menu-input" type="radio" checked>
    <div class=menu-item>Menu 1</div>
    <div class="menu-pane">
      <h1>Page one</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis viverra mattis ex in tempor. Cras elementum sagittis rutrum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input name="menu-input" type="radio">
    <div class=menu-item>Menu 2</div>
    <div class="menu-pane">
      <h1>Page two</h1>
      <p>
        Ut consectetur, purus eu suscipit ultrices, ligula eros laoreet erat, et lobortis velit tellus et ligula. Donec sed aliquam lacus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input name="menu-input" type="radio">
    <div class=menu-item>Menu 3</div>
    <div class="menu-pane">
      <h1>Page three</h1>
      <p>
        Phasellus ornare ultricies nisi sit amet viverra. Curabitur eleifend urna in massa posuere, vitae aliquet enim tempor. Donec lacinia bibendum purus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input name="menu-input" type="radio">
    <div class=menu-item>Menu 4</div>
    <div class="menu-pane">
      <h1>Page four</h1>
      <p>
        Integer fermentum, diam a semper porttitor, odio dui vulputate elit, a fringilla quam ante ut enim. In pulvinar in mauris ut faucibus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input name="menu-input" type="radio">
    <div class=menu-item>Menu 5</div>
    <div class="menu-pane">
      <h1>Page five</h1>
      <p>
        Fusce sed orci faucibus dolor consequat tempus. Nunc nisl magna, pellentesque et dictum vitae, eleifend et mauris.
      </p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input name="menu-input" type="radio">
    <div class=menu-item>Menu 6</div>
    <div class="menu-pane">
      <h1>Page six</h1>
      <p>
        Ut dictum commodo consectetur. Aliquam mollis egestas vestibulum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </p>
    </div>
  </label>
</nav>
```

Generally the benefits of doing something like this is speed. Though it can be a little confusing to use.

Comment: @PankajMorajkar I've tinkered a little more https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/ebrmcgbn/

Comment: @Andrew...works perfectly in your fiddle...but giving me some issues on the site...let me play around with it ...thanks for all your help..